# Plot GDAL raster using matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot a raster tiff *([download](https://files.myopera.com/mvanhoek/files/albers_5km.tif)-723Kb)* using matplotlib Basemap. My raster's projection coordinates is in meter:

```
In  [2]:
path = r'albers_5km.tif'
raster = gdal.Open(path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
array = raster.GetRasterBand(20).ReadAsArray()

print ('Raster Projection:\n', raster.GetProjection())
print ('Raster GeoTransform:\n', raster.GetGeoTransform())

Out [2]:
Raster Projection:
 PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",15],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",65],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",30],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",95],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Raster GeoTransform:
 (190425.8243, 5000.0, 0.0, 1500257.0112, 0.0, -5000.0)
```

If I try to plot this using a Robin projection using `contourf` with `latlon=False` than x and y are assumed to be map projection coordinates (see [docs](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.basemap), I think that's what I have).

But if I look to the plot I notice it's placed bottom left very small:

[image: bottom-left]

Using this code:

```
In  [3]:
xy = raster.GetGeoTransform() 
x = raster.RasterXSize 
y = raster.RasterYSize    
lon_start = xy[0] 
lon_stop = x*xy[1]+xy[0] 
lon_step = xy[1]    
lat_start = xy[3] 
lat_stop = y*xy[5]+xy[3] 
lat_step = xy[5]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10)) 
map = Basemap(projection='robin',resolution='c',lat_0=0,lon_0=0)

lons = np.arange(lon_start, lon_stop, lon_step) 
lats = np.arange(lat_start, lat_stop, lat_step)    
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

levels = [array.min(),-0.128305,array.max()] 
map.contourf(xx, yy,array, levels, cmap=cm.RdBu_r, latlon=False)

map.colorbar(cntr,location='right',pad='10%')    
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.5) 
map.drawcountries(color='red')
```

Eventually I don't want to have a world view but a detailed view. But this gives me a zoom level where the coastlines and countries are drawn, but data is again placed in bottom left corner, but not as small as previous time:

[image: again bottom-left]

Using the following code:

```
In  [4]:
extent = [ xy[0],xy[0]+x*xy[1], xy[3],xy[3]+y*xy[5]]
width_x = (extent[1]-extent[0])*10
height_y = (extent[2]-extent[3])*10

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
map = Basemap(projection='stere', resolution='c', width = width_x , height = height_y, lat_0=40.2,lon_0=99.6,)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
levels = [array.min(),-0.128305,array.max()]
map.contourf(xx, yy, array, levels, cmap=cm.RdBu_r, latlon=False)

map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.5)
map.drawcountries(color='red')
```

Comment: shouldnt it be projection='stereo' ? (missing an 'o' there is probably just a typo)

Comment: No, it says 'stereo' is an unsupported projection. 'stere' is used for Stereographic projection

Comment: Strange, if i would make something short for stereographic, it d be stereo instead of stere ;-) But maybe all abbreviations of projections are 5 characters or so.

Comment: You are plotting Albers (AEA) coordinates as if they are Robinson or Stereographic. You need to reproject your `xx` and `yy` to your map projection before plotting.

Comment: @RutgerKassies. Thank you for pointing this out! I thought it was doing this on the fly. Can I reproject my xx and yy using Basemap? Secondly when I change projection from 'stere' to 'aea', I would expect it will be displayed right, but it's still displayed as seen above.

Comment: @Mattijn, Im not entirely sure if Basemap can do it, i would think so though. I see you already have GDAL, so using GDAL's `ct.TransformPoints()` would certainly work. I wouldnt mind making an example for you, but not immediately, i have some other work first. If you make plots like this a lot, also have a look at Cartopy, that certainly has an on-the-fly option: http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery.html

Comment: @RutgerKassies Ok, take your time. An example would be very much appreciated. I will have a look to Cartopy and TransformPoints, from which I both haven't heard about before.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the following code to convert the coordinates, it automatically takes the projection from your raster as the source and the projection from your Basemap object as the target coordinate system.

#### Imports

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import osr, gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

#### Coordinate conversion

```
def convertXY(xy_source, inproj, outproj):
    # function to convert coordinates
    
    shape = xy_source[0,:,:].shape
    size = xy_source[0,:,:].size

    # the ct object takes and returns pairs of x,y, not 2d grids
    # so the the grid needs to be reshaped (flattened) and back.
    ct = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inproj, outproj)
    xy_target = np.array(ct.TransformPoints(xy_source.reshape(2, size).T))

    xx = xy_target[:,0].reshape(shape)
    yy = xy_target[:,1].reshape(shape)
    
    return xx, yy
```

#### Reading and processing the data

```
# Read the data and metadata
ds = gdal.Open(r'albers_5km.tif')

data = ds.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

xres = gt[1]
yres = gt[5]

# get the edge coordinates and add half the resolution 
# to go to center coordinates
xmin = gt[0] + xres * 0.5
xmax = gt[0] + (xres * ds.RasterXSize) - xres * 0.5
ymin = gt[3] + (yres * ds.RasterYSize) + yres * 0.5
ymax = gt[3] - yres * 0.5

ds = None

# create a grid of xy coordinates in the original projection
xy_source = np.mgrid[ymax+yres:ymin:yres, xmin:xmax+xres:xres]
```

#### Plotting

```
# Create the figure and basemap object
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
m = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, resolution='c')

# Create the projection objects for the convertion
# original (Albers)
inproj = osr.SpatialReference()
inproj.ImportFromWkt(proj)

# Get the target projection from the basemap object
outproj = osr.SpatialReference()
outproj.ImportFromProj4(m.proj4string)

# Convert from source projection to basemap projection
xx, yy = convertXY(xy_source, inproj, outproj)

# plot the data (first layer)
im1 = m.pcolormesh(xx, yy, data[0,:,:], cmap=plt.cm.jet, shading='auto')

# annotate
m.drawcountries()
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=.5)

plt.savefig('world.png',dpi=75)
```

[image]

If you need the pixels location to be 100% correct you might want to check the creation of the coordinate arrays **really careful** yourself (because i didn't at all). This example should hopefully set you on the right track.

Comment: This puts me on the right track, indeed. All the credits to you for this great answer. To be able to do both the analysis and the plotting in a Python environment is really nice.

Comment: Dear Rutger Kassies, is this approach valid when using Cartopy too?

Comment: May I know what has to be changed in the above code if there is only 1 band in the raster image?

Comment: @SaiKiran, it probably depends on how many dimensions you have. But if yours is 2D, you probably need to change this: `data[0,:,:]` into just `data`.

Comment: @RutgerKassies Thanks. Could you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64693088/assign-color-to-polygon-shapefile-in-matplotlib-basemap-based-on-its-correspondi

Comment: @RutgerKassies Hello. I've been trying to reproduce your code but unfortunetely without any sucess at all. I'm able to plot the whole global contours with basemap, but my gdal figure doesn't show up. I also got this warning message: `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: shading='flat' when X and Y have the same dimensions as C is deprecated since 3.3.  Either specify the corners of the quadrilaterals with X and Y, or pass shading='auto', 'nearest' or 'gouraud', or set rcParams['pcolor.shading'].` Already tried to set other shadind options, but the error persists.

Comment: @GabrielLucas, I've made some edits to the post. Flipped the coordinate generation with np.mgrid, removed the transpose of the data, and added `shading="auto"`. That gets rid of the warning for me. Also checkout Cartopy if Basemap doesn't work for you.

Comment: @RutgerKassies Nice, this modification also worked for me. Thank you for your attention and support!