# Plot .tif GDAL raster using matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, gdal, matplotlib-basemap

I have a bit of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20499331/1533001) that I am using for plotting a geotiff image ([Landsat](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov)):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from osgeo import osr, gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Read the data and metadata
ds = gdal.Open(filename)

data = ds.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

xres = gt[1]
yres = gt[5]

# get the edge coordinates and add half the resolution 
# to go to center coordinates
xmin = gt[0] + xres * 0.5
xmax = gt[0] + (xres * ds.RasterXSize) - xres * 0.5
ymin = gt[3] + (yres * ds.RasterYSize) + yres * 0.5
ymax = gt[3] - yres * 0.5

ds = None

# create a grid of xy coordinates in the original projection
xy_source = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax+xres:xres, ymax+yres:ymin:yres]
# Create the figure and basemap object
m = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, resolution='c')

# Create the projection objects for the convertion
inproj = osr.SpatialReference()
inproj.ImportFromWkt(proj)

# Get the target projection from the basemap object
outproj = osr.SpatialReference()
outproj.ImportFromProj4(m.proj4string)

size = xy_source[0,:,:].size
ct = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inproj, outproj)
xy_target = np.array(ct.TransformPoints(xy_source.reshape(2, size).T))
```

But, it fails at `ct.TransformPoints(xy_source.reshape(2, size).T))` and I'm not sure why. The error it gives me:

> TypeError: in method 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoints', argument 1 of type 'OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow *'

Which I do not understand. Any OSR guru's out there?

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT 1** The projection of my .TIFF

```
>>> print proj
Out[20]: 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 34N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",21],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32634"]]'
```

Also,

```
>>> m.proj4string
Out[43]: '+lon_0=0.0 +y_0=8615499.05007 +R=6370997.0 +proj=robin +x_0=16986796.165 +units=m '
```

Comment: It sounds like your input data might not have a projection defined.  What does `proj` look like?  (i.e. after doing `proj = ds.GetProjection()` put in `print proj`).

Comment: Try using `osr.UseExceptions()` at the top. What were the `proj` and `m.proj4string` inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install the `proj4` package. Otherwise, the input projection is not understood by `osr`.

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jgomezdans proj4
```